# xlsxwriter insert_image <unknown>.insert_image

Tags: python, xlsxwriter, insert-image

I want to insert an image to Excel document, and I try to use xlsxwriter insert_image, but it said unknown.insert_image.

```
      from win32com import client
        xlApp = client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
        workbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open('test.xlsx')
        worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[0]
        worksheet.insert_image('F4','logo.png')
        worksheet.Visible = 1
        worksheet.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, 'D:\\Python\\whatever\\test.pdf')
        workbook.close()
```

it raised

Exception "unhandled AttributeError"
unknown.insert_image

Comment: This is an example for xlsxwriter.  http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_images.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing 2 incompatible objects in this  example `client.Dispatch("Excel.Application").Workbooks.Open('name')` and `xlsxwriter.Workbook`.

You need to use the equivalent method to `xlsxwriter.worksheet.insert_image()` in the other object/class.

Maybe try the syntax from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22464488/formatting-image-in-excel-using-win32com-client).

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, and finally I use openpyxl to replace